# How to merge repository with backend to frontend?

Tags: git

I have a backend code in framework and I have several websites which uses the backend code with different frontend for each of them.

I want to merge or update the repository with the frontend, but I want to update the backend only and not the frontend. I don't want to overwrite it. Because the backend contains (models, controllers and views) the view is separated into two Modules:

- AdminModule -> "Frontend" administration which is same for everybody.
- FrontendModule -> Frontend for each site is different.

I want to update it with AdminModule, but not with FrontendModule, do you know how to do it?

Comment: you can add `AdminModule` and `FrontendModule` in `.gitignore` and push it to git, so after that only changes in the code other then these module will be update on git when you push it.

Comment: Consider using something else for dependency management?

Comment: What do you thing about using something else for dependency management?